# Using ASP.NET MVC model classes in a Windows Forms application

Tags: winforms, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use ASP.NET MVC model classes in a Windows Forms application? I referenced the .dll file of my ASP.NET MVC project from my Windows Forms application and I was successfully able to call the models. However, when I tried to build the project, errors suddenly popped up saying the namespace of the ASP.NET MVC project could not be found even though the reference was intact.

Here is one of the issue classes in the Windows Forms Application "BeerRecommenderHelper" that references classes in the ASP.NET MVC 3 project "BeerRecommender":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using BeerRecommender.Models;

namespace BeerRecommenderHelper.Models
{
    public class BeerRecommenderHelperContext : BeerRecommender.Models.BeerRecommenderContext
    {

        public DbSet<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Recommendation> Recommendations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new BeerRecommenderInitializer());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have your model classes in a separate project, and thes project doesn't contain any references that are specific for an MVC or web project you're free to use the models in your winform project. If both projects use the same 'backend' logic than i would suggest this a good approach!

What are the errors you get when building the project?

Comment: It says "The type or namespace <name of class in MVC project> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I have the using directive and it's able to figure it out until it tries to compile.

Comment: Can you post the class? Also include the usings you have in your model.

Comment: I just edited the question to include one of the classes with the problem.

Comment: Do you need System.Web in your model? Also which version of .Net are you using in your winform app? Have you added a reference to System.Data.Entity to your winform app?

Comment: I don't need System.Web. I have removed it. According to the project properties, the target framework is ".NET framework 4 Client Profile". And yes, there is a reference to System.Data.Entity in the winform app.

Comment: Did you do a clean solution/rebuild, checked other classes that have references to System.Web? Is the updated dll copied to the bin folder?

Comment: I don't think any of my model classes that I reference rely on System.Web so they shouldn't be necessary. After cleaning and rebuilding the ASP.NET MVC project and then doing the same for the Winforms project, I still received the same error. It's just odd that it only stops working once I try to build the winforms.